# Mysql SELECT not working

Tags: mysql, join

I have the tables:

**users**

```
ID | RANK | NAME | EMAIL       | PASS
01 |  1   | Foo  | foo@bar.com | $06$uhAMXXZowVIDQ.ZR1gky.u3f/UBkLW8Kd8cbyDt2eNx1qnZH2AUmW
```

**allow**

```
ID | RANK | STEP
01 |  1   |  1
02 |  1   |  2
03 |  1   |  3
04 |  2   |  1
05 |  4   |  *
```

And, I need to know all allowed steps from user rank.

**My code:**

```
SELECT users.*, allow.step AS allow_step
  FROM users AS users LEFT JOIN allow ON users.rank = allow.rank
```

But only one step are selected.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can't you just use two separate queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a.step) allow_step 
     FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN allow a 
       ON u.rank = a.rank
 GROUP BY a.rank_id
```

This should select a list of steps separated by commas. Something like `1,2,3`.

---

If you need the concatenated values to be ordered, change the first line of the query to:

```
   SELECT u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a.step ORDER BY a.step) allow_step
```

Answer (score 0):

The given SQL and data will yield three rows - and would even without the use of a LEFT JOIN (a simple JOIN would suffice).

You don't show or describe how you are running the SQL; do you need to fetch multiple rows in a loop, or use some 'fetch all rows' method?

Comment: If users.rank is a foreign key not allowing nulls that references allow.rank, then an inner join will work fine.  If there isn't an FK relationship, why not?  If you allow NULL in users.rank - why did you set yourself up with problems?  (Why not provide a suitable default, non-NULL, rank to use.)

Comment: I'm a newbie brazilian mysql developer, I understand the practices but not theory.